# Separating plural possessive apostrophe from closing double-quote

Tags: punctuation

Let's say that I have a plural noun that I am trying to make the possessive form of, for example, `butchers'`.  Let's say that for some reason I need to enclose this word directly inside double-quotes, such as would be written as `"butchers'"` in ordinary text. Let's say that as a result of this, I end up with TeX code like:

```
We must take these ``butchers''' words at face value.
```

which then ends up rendering with the equivalent of:

```
We must take these "butchers"' words at face value.
```

Is there any way to indicate to TeX that the `'''` should be grouped as one and then two, instead of two and then one?  I have tried variants such as:

```
``butchers'\ ''

``butchers\'''

``butchers`''

``butchers'%
 ''
```

none of which worked.

Comment: `butchers'{}''`

Comment: and also: butchers{'}''

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the linked-to one didn't come up in my search - I figured someone would have asked it before but I had a hell of a time finding it.